# Convolution and fractional operator

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convolution, fractional-calculus

Let $h\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ and consider the equation
$$(-\Delta)^s u = h,$$
where $(-\Delta)^s u$ denotes the fractional Laplacian of $u$.
Let $\Gamma$ be its fundamental solution, i.e. $(-\Delta)^s \Gamma =\delta$, where $\delta $ stands for the Dirac delta at $0$.

At class (but it is written also in many examples on my textbook) it is written that, under these conditions, setting $\bar u = u-\Gamma\ast h$, follows that $\bar u$ solves the problem
$$(\ast)\quad (-\Delta)^s \bar u = 0.$$

Why is that true?
I mean, I can understand on my own that
$$(-\Delta)^s u = h,\quad (-\Delta)^s (\Gamma\ast h) =\delta\ast h = h,$$
but why is $(\ast)$ true?

Comment: Hint: Use the linearity of the fractional Laplacian.

Comment: @junjios, do you mean that $(-\Delta)^s(u+v) = (-\Delta)^s(u) + (-\Delta)^s(v)$?

Comment: Yes, its a linear operator. This is clear from the integral definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Laplacian